# Create 'description' file (maybe XSD file?) from randomly supplied XML files

Tags: php, xml, linux, perl, xsd

I am trying to create an application that allows people to present a xml feed and then select certain fields from the feed to be included in a tweet.

I would like to somehow validate the xml feed without an existing schema and I'm not really bothered whether it conforms as long as it is well formed and consistent.

Are there any classes or programmatic tools I could access from php or perl that would allow help with this. I haven't got the time to build it myself ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've used [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). It's Java, but you can just do:

```
java -jar trang.jar input.xml output.xsd
```

This way it'll create the XSD schema based on the XML file.